# How would you get started if you want to make a game for google actions

Tags: dialogflow-es, webhooks, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have created an action, and I have a basic understanding of DialogFlow, how would I get started if I wanted to make a Text adventure (More like Voice adventure) for the google assistant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this story on writing [The Magnificent Escape Action](https://medium.com/google-developers/the-magnificent-escape-action-97b1bc03942e), which discusses many of the things you're looking to do.

Otherwise, "getting started" is just like designing any other voice action (and like most programs):

- [Design](https://actions.google.com/design) what you want to do

  - Determine the [personality](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/conversation/conversation-design-process/create-a-persona.html) you want your Action to have
  - Create the [scripts](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/conversation/conversation-design-process/write-sample-dialogs.html) for the Action, exploring the various things [your player may say](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1), and keeping your persona in mind with how you reply
- Build Dialogflow [Intents](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/conversation-to-code-part-1-3e4584371783) that capture the phrases in the scripts
- Add [logic](https://medium.com/@afirstenberg/conversation-to-code-part-2-39b74b0e7b0f) to handle these Intents

Comment: ok, any other sources you can provide that would give helpful information?

Comment: Considering the question was put on hold as too broad, you're lucky you got this much. {: If you do need more information beyond those articles and the various links from them, asking specific questions is probably best. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Again, if you have specific questions or problems, feel free to post them as new questions.

Comment: Part of the problem is StackExchange frowns anything that isn't a VERY specific problem or question. In this case I'm basically looking for a mini getting started guide and that's just not basically StackExchange allows.

Comment: Well, you've indicated you've already created an Action, so you're a bit beyond getting started. And I pointed you at an article that discussed a number of things about getting started with text adventures. If there is something that you feel is missing or that you don't understand from all those items, we can provide more guidance, but I'm not sure what more can help to get you started at this stage.